# Django / error : Object of type *** is not JSON serializable

Tags: django

I have seen this is a common mistake and there are a lot of entries in StackOverflow, but I can't connect the dots on this one.

in my views.py, this one works

```
def start(request):

    whichScene = request.session.get('whichScene')
   
    myScene=Scenes.objects.get(name=whichScene)
    scene_list=myScene.next.all()

    return render(request,'scenes3d/start.html',
         {'scene_list':scene_list})
```

this one doesn't work :

```
def newPage (request, scene_slug):
   
    sceneToRender = Scenes.objects.get(name=scene_slug)

    return render(request,'scenes3d/new_scene.html',
        {"myScene" :sceneToRender })
```

It gives an error :

*Exception Value:*  *Object of type Scenes is not JSON serializable*

Scenes is imported with :

```
from .models import Scenes
```

models.py

```
class Scenes(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField('Scene name', max_length=60,unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    fileGltf = models.FileField(null=TRUE, blank=False, upload_to="3dfiles/")
    
    record_date = models.DateTimeField('Scene date')

    manager = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  
    prev = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', 
        related_name='next',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the queryset `sceneToRender = Scenes.objects.get(name=scene_slug)` is not a single object (which would be JSON serializable) you need to access the `values` of by using this instead:

```
sceneToRender = Scenes.objects.get(name=scene_slug).values()
```

Then you can render your view.

Comment: Not sure I understand your point : 'Scenes' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Something else you could do is convert your query into a list and then use json.dumps() to pass it to your render function:
```sceneToRender = list(Scenes.objects.get(name=scene_slug))

    return render(request,'scenes3d/new_scene.html',
        {"myScene" : json.dumps(sceneToRender) })
```
(you need to import json on top of your view file first)